# Inserting PHP code in drupal module

Tags: php, drupal-7

I've an iframe in my custom drupal 7 module whihch is displaying data from a remote url like this:-

```
$element[$delta]['#markup'] = '<iframe class="page_flipper" src="someURL"></iframe>';
```

It is working well but I want to display the output of another script/program in this iframe. The program has combined code of HTML,CSS,JavaScript and PHP. In other words I want to integrate that program in the above iframe. Can anybody tell how can I do this?

I've tried to point to the program using relative path in the src attribute of the iframe like this:-

```
$element[$delta]['#markup'] = '<iframe class="page_flipper" src="mydir/index.php"></iframe>';
```

but it didn't work and drupal displays this error in the iframe `"The requested page "/<site_name>/node/myFlip/index.php" could not be found.` Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what happens when you use the absolute path instead of the relative path? seems like that should fix the issue

Comment: When I try to use absolute path using DOCUMENT_ROOT, the same error appears. It looks like drupal look for the index.php in some "node" directory not in the current module directory as the error above reflects.

Comment: I missed the whole part about it being a custom module and was thinking you were dealing with a script that was outside of teh drupal root. See my answer below, it's along the same lines as what Amar proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the snippet below do the trick?

```
// Get the path to the module..
$module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE');

// Prepend with the Drupal root..
$path = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $module_path . '/mydir/index.php'; 

// Use..
$element[$delta]['#markup'] = 
  "<iframe class='page_flipper' src='$path'></iframe>";
```

Safer to put the folder with the PHP script in the root of your Drupal installation, I feel. Then you can just access it with:

```
global $base_url;
$path = $base_url . '/ext/index.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Drupals drupal_get_path() and url() functions to build an absolute url to the file.

```
$iframe_url = url(drupal_get_path('module','MYMODULE').'/mydir/index.php',array('absolute'=>true));

$element[$delta]['#markup'] = "<iframe class='page_flipper' src='$iframe_url'></iframe>";
```